# How to connect to DB2 server from same machine?

Tags: db2, client

I have a system where DB2 server is installed on Linux as user x.
I want to connect to the server using db2 command from a user other than x.
How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: The process is not that much different from connecting remotely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796518/how-to-connect-with-a-remote-db2-server-from-another-db2-instance-on-aix

Answer (score 0):

With the DB2 command line, you specify the user in your [connect statement](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.comref/src/tpc/db2z_clpconnectsyntax.html):

```
db2 CONNECT TO dbname USER x
```

You can specify the password on the command by adding `USING your_password` on the end, but I would leave that off so the command will prompt you to put it in (so it's not echoed back to your command windows).

Once you are done, you can disconnect by doing

```
db2 CONNECT RESET
```

Comment: Do we need to source anything to get db2 ?                                                Do we need to catalog the database ?